# One of my navbar links not working bootstrap

Tags: html

Hi I have just one of my navbar links that aren't working and I can't seem to resolve it myself. I have included my nav code and it's the pricing section that won't work and I have the section id as #pricing

https://codepen.io/hollyj24/pen/eYZWgwb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <a href="#"><img class="navbar-brand" src="images\logo.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your code so we can better assist you? Also what happens when you click it?

Comment: @Si8 A Stack Snippet is preferred rather than a fiddle, as it is included directly in the question instead of having to go to an external site.

Comment: @H_J_ There is not enough information here to be able to help. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see all the relevant code that might be causing the problem so we can help.

Comment: Just a heads up you are also missing a closing </li> tag for your third nav-item in the code provided.

Comment: Sorry it is my first question i'll try again!

Comment: What happens when you click on it?

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Comment: I have now uploaded it to codepen? I hope that's what everyone meant for me to do! Thanks

Comment: Your ID is currently `<section id="#pricing">`, you don't need the `#` when setting an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code in CodePen. In line 111, you have said:

```
<section id="#pricing">
```

Remove the hashtag, and it should work. This is saying that the `id` of this section is `#pricing`, when you want it to be `pricing`.

Just to understand it better, on line 37, change it to:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="##pricing">Pricing <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

This will also work, but this isn't what you want. Change line 111 to `<section id="pricing">`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple thing I did wrong!

Comment: That's what coding's about :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove id # from pricing Section on line 112

```
id="#pricing"
```

write

```
id = "pricing"
```